# possible for a surjective function have an element in the domain not mapped to the range?

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

A function f is surjective if and only for every element of the range corresponds to at least one member of the domain, but is it possible for an element in the domain don't have a corresponding element in the range ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would violate the definition of a function/ the definition of the range of a function.